# Android push notifications - how can I extract the device id?

Tags: android

From the Google cloud push tutorials, I am running this code when a user first starts the app:

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) 
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "566530471892");
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
```

But what I don't understand is how to send that regId variable to the server so I can save it along with the new user id.

Or am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? Is that not the correct thing to do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what I don't understand is how to send that regId variable to the server so I can save it along with the new user id.

You do it by whatever means you are otherwise communicating with your server, such as a Web service call.

Comment: right, I know how to send the id to my server.  I just don't know how to extract the id :) In the if check the id is empty, and in the else call the id is registered. So do I send it from the else call? I got confused by the order of how things happen.  I thought initially it is not registered.

Comment: @Genadinik: "So do I send it from the else call?" -- it is supplied to your `onRegistered()` method in your `GCMIntentService`. Most likely, you would not bother with the `else` block you have above, and simply handle it in `onRegistered()`, particularly since you are already on a background thread there and can safely do a Web service call.

Comment: sorry I am still confused.  So when is the onRegistered() called? Is it invoked by the app without me invoking that, and my getRegistrationId() call would simply get that id? Or do I need to sweak something in the GCMIntentService?  Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik: "So when is the onRegistered() called?" -- sometime after you call `GCMRegistrar.register()`, assuming everything goes OK. If there is some sort of problem, you may get `onError()` or `onRecoverableError()` instead. These will be called automatically based upon the fact that you called `GCMRegistrar.register()`.